# Jenkins Pipelines: not including files created by pipeline in deploy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have implemented docker based build images for jenkins with apparent success - except for the fact that it is not doing everything I asked it to anymore.

This pipeline worked as desired when running on the main jenkins node.

I changed `agent { any }` to this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'php8' }
    .
    .
    .

}
```

and in the deploy stage I have this:

```
    stage ('Deploy') {
        parallel {
            stage ("Deploy code") {
                agent { label 'php8' }
                steps {
                    ..
                }
            }
            ..
        }
    }
```

My experience is that in my staging steps I delete some folders and generate a config file, but the folders are still there, and the config file is absent.
everything happens so fast that I have not checked whether my Jenkins Server spawns an extra pod, but the result is that I only get the raw contents of the git repo, and not the config file, nor the composer vendor folder, or autoload.php

Besides making the pods dump the list of files they are working on to the jenkins log, how can i ensyre that the deploy step is executed on the same folder in the same pod as the staging step?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was apparently to just remove the `agent` label.

```
    stage ('Deploy') {
        parallel {
            stage ("Deploy code") {
                steps {
                    ..
                }
            }
            ..
        }
    }
```